# Openshot Video Editor + Blender--ERROR!

Tags: blender, openshot

I'm using a Video Editor called Openshot, and it uses Blender. However, I keep getting this error:

> Blender, the free open source 3D content creation suite is required
>   for this action (http://www.blender.org).
>
> Please check the preferences in OpenShot and be sure the Blender
>   executable is correct.  This setting should be the path of the
>   'blender' executable on your computer.  Also, please be sure that it
>   is pointing to Blender version 2.62 or greater.

Blender Path:

```
/home/alexandra/blender/blender-2.74/blender
```

I've changed the blender path to

```
/home/alexandra/blender/blender-2.74/blender
```

as well as trying every online tutorial I can find. I don't know If I've mistyped the blender path or what, but some help would really be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is likely incorrect. You can obtain the correct path by opening a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> often does the trick) and issuing the command `which blender` the result will be the path you need. You can confirm that you have a supported version of blender with the command `blender --version` The version currently in the repositories is Blender 2.69 (at least for "Trusty" Ubuntu 14.04) you can properly install it easily with the command `sudo apt-get install blender`

Comment: Perfect-It worked!!!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to help!!!